# Does $C'\left(\frac{5}{11}\right)$ imply exponential growth?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I came across this rather week small cancellation condition $C'\left(\frac{5}{11}\right)$ of a group $G$. It has been proved that $C'\left(\frac16\right)$ is enough for $G$ to contain free subgroups. I was therefore wondering if $\frac{5}{11}$ is maybe enough to still have exponential growth.

Does anyone know of any related papers or results?

Comment: Doesn't $\mathbb{Z}^2$ satisfy $C'(5/11)$?  Or have I misremembered the definition? (You should probably give the definition.)

Comment: @HW: Yes, of course: $5/11 > 1/4$. 

Comment: Mark - I agree with your inequality!  Hence my wanting to check I'd remembered the definition correctly.

Comment: The question should probably be about 2/11 which is between 1/5 and 1/6.

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful comments! Denis, would it have exponential growth if it was 2/11?

Comment: I would ask a more specific question. Does $\mathbb Z^2$ have a $C'(1/6+\varepsilon)$-presentation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every finitely presented group has presentation satisfying $C'(1/5)$. Note that $1/5 < 5/11$. See the book by Olshanskii's book "Geometry of defining relations of groups".

Comment: It is A.I.Golberg's theorem (1978). The proof can be found in Olshanskii's book, but not in the book of Lyndon and Schupp (1977), I think.  

Comment: @Anton: You are right!

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. The groups I am looking at are infinitely presented. Are there any partial results known for such cases?

Comment: If the group is not finitely presented, the situation is different. At least you know, by Gromov's theorem, that the group cannot have polynomial growth. I do not know if Grigorchuk group or other groups of intermediate growth can have $C'(5/11)$-presentation. You can check the Lysenok presentation of Grigorchuk group. 

Comment: Lysenok's presentation does not satisfy $C'(5/11)$ because of the relations $a^2=1, b^2=1, c^2=1, d^2=1$. One probably needs to look at other groups. There are torsion-free groups of intermediate growth constructed in R. I. Grigorchuk. Degrees of growth of p-groups and torsion-free groups. Mat. Sb. (N.S.),
126(168)(2):194–214, 286, 1985.  

Comment: Many thanks for this!

The group $G$ that I have is also one acting on rooted trees defined by a sequence of distinct prime valences $\left\{l_i\right\}$ on each level. 

If $l_i < 2 l_{i+1}$ then $G$ has $C'(5/11)$. It is not torsion. However, I was only able to show exponential growth if $l_i > exp\left(5 C^i \prod_{j=1}^{i-1} l_j\right)$. It further does not contain non-cyclic free subgroups if $l_i > \left(25 l_{i-1}\right)^{3 \prod_{j=1}^{i-1} l_j}$. 

Is is open whether a group of this kind contains a free semigroup (which is probably independent of the sequence $\left\{l_i\right\}$).

Comment: It seems that Golberg's theorem remains valid for non-finitely presented groups. Just check the proof in Olshanskii's book. Do you see any problems? 

Comment: @Anton: I do not have the book with me. It could be true that the same proof works. 
